# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MVC_Web_App.Models.Products'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am designing a test application 
, the controller is

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditSingleProduct(string PrdNm)
    {
        try
        {
            List<Products> ProductGrid = new List<Products>();
            string UserAdded = Session["User"].ToString();
            SqlConnection Prodct = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString());
            Prodct.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("", Prodct))
            {
                command.CommandText = "Select * from [Rush].[dbo].[Product] where ProductName='" + PrdNm + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

                DataTable dtTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
                foreach (DataRow dr in dtTable.Rows)
                {
                    Products Prd1 = new Products();
                    Prd1.ProductName = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
                    Prd1.ProductType = dr["ProductType"].ToString();
                    Prd1.ProductPrice = dr["ProductPrice"].ToString();
                    Prd1.Quality1 = dr["Quality1"].ToString();
                    Prd1.Quality2 = dr["Quality2"].ToString();
                    Prd1.Quality3 = dr["Quality3"].ToString();
                    ProductGrid.Add(Prd1);
                }


            }
            return View(ProductGrid.ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

and the View is

```
    <title>EditSingleProduct</title>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{@Html.TextBoxFor(Prd1 => Prd1.ProductName, new { @class = "form-control text-center", placeholder = "Product Name" })                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Prd1 => Prd1.ProductName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Prd1 => Prd1.ProductType, new {@class = "form-control text-center", placeholder = "Product Type" })                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Prd1 => Prd1.ProductType)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Prd1 => Prd1.ProductPrice, new {@class = "form-control text-center", placeholder = "Product Price" })                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Prd1 => Prd1.ProductPrice)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Prd1 => Prd1.Quality1, new { @class = "form-control text-center", placeholder = "Specification-I" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Prd1 => Prd1.Quality1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Prd1 => Prd1.Quality2, new { @class = "form-control text-center", placeholder = "Specification-II" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Prd1 => Prd1.Quality2)
@Html.TextBoxFor(Prd1 => Prd1.Quality3, new {@class = "form-control text-center", placeholder = "Specification-III" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Prd1 => Prd1.Quality3)
<input type="submit" id="Updatebtn" value="Update Product" class="btn" />
```

but i am not able to get data
the sql is working fine i am getting one item as requested in for each loop i just want to fill the textbox with that data , the the user may edit the textbox and update the data and the HTTP post code is working fine

Comment: Format your code correctly and include the details of the error message in your question (and your returning a collection to the view but your view appears to be based on a single `Products`, not a collection

Comment: At the top of your view should be `@model xxx` the xxx should match the type of the bit inside `return View(xxx);`.  The error message is telling you that they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to pass a collection to your view that's designed for a single object.

Comment: added turn View(ProductGrid.ToList().FirstOrDefault());